# SingleTable Strategy, if table name not specified in subclass, cast exception?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I have a single table hierarchy shown below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "v_contract_account", schema = "SAP")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({CurrencyAccount.class, ProgramAccount.class})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class AbstractContractAccount implements Serializable {
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "v_contract_account", schema = "SAP")
@Immutable
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CurrencyAccount extends AbstractContractAccount  {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "v_contract_account", schema = "SAP")
@Immutable
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProgramAccount extends AbstractContractAccount {
    ...
}
```

Right now it works as it is (except the discriminator stuff), but why is it that if I remove the table annotation from the subclass, Hibernate will throw an exception?

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse cannot be cast to [Lcom.zanox.internal.billingmasterdata.domain.entity.CurrencyAccount;
```

And the strange thing is, if I don't put the table and inheritance annotation in the abstract super class, everything still works fine. Does this mean MappedSuperClass doesn't care about the table and inheritance annotation? If the annotation @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) is not needed anywhere, then where do I specify it?

Btw, in my case here, Hibernate doesn't create the table, the table is there already and I just want to map it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to remove the @MappedSuperClass annotation from your parent Entity and make it a normal Entity.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

If you wanted to query across AbstractContractAccount then it has to be an Entity. You can cannot do this when it is a MappedSuperclass.

You would use @MappedSuperClass when you wanted to defined some common mapings but where there was no actual 'database inheritance'.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

> Mapped superclass inheritance allows inheritance to be used in the
>   object model, when it does not exist in the data model. It is similar
>   to table per class inheritance, but does not allow querying,
>   persisting, or relationships to the superclass. Its main purpose is to
>   allow mappings information to be inherited by its subclasses. The
>   subclasses are responsible for defining the table, id and other
>   information, and can modify any of the inherited mappings. A common
>   usage of a mapped superclass is to define a common PersistentObject
>   for your application to define common behavior and mappings such as
>   the id and version. A mapped superclass normally should be an abstract
>   class. A mapped superclass is not an Entity but is instead defined
>   though the @MappedSuperclass annotation or the 
>   element.

Comment: So MappedSuperClass's job is just really a mapping and there's no actual database inheritance. Thanks for clarifying the difference!